# SKStoreReviewController not working on changing the device time to future date (e.g. 15 or more days ahead)

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am struggling to find out the reason why `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` not showing me review pop up while in development, if i change the my device time to some future time like 15 days ahead. Moreover it hang my device and i need to kill my application.

Anybody knows the reason for it.

Comment: In development, `requestReview` should show the review popup every time. See the documentation for `requestReview`.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, Its showing me every time but as i said its not showing me when i change the device date to any future date. eg. 15 or more days ahead of current date.

Comment: @VarunMehta did you find out why this happens? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: FYI, this issue occurs only on iOS 12